# el mi_lista.pop() no me permite borrar la lista 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

[![El mi_lista.pop() no me permite borrar la lista 3][1]][1]

Usando el codigo mi_lista.pop() puedo borrar lista de orden como 0, 1, 2 y 4, pero no puedo borrar la lista 3. La lista 3 fue anteriormente agregado por mi_lista.insert y no puedo borrarlo.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sr1pS.png

```
#!C:\python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

mi_lista = ["Pato", "Gallina", "Pollo", "Pato", "Pavo"]

print(mi_lista)

mi_lista.append("Avestruz")

print(mi_lista)

print(mi_lista.count("Pato"))

mi_lista.extend(["Gato", "Perro"])

print(mi_lista)

mi_lista.index("Pato")

print(mi_lista)

mi_lista.insert(3, "Lechuga")

print(mi_lista)

print(mi_lista.pop())

print(mi_lista)

mi_lista.remove("Lechuga")

print(mi_lista)

mi_lista.reverse()

print(mi_lista)

mi_lista.sort()

print(mi_lista)

input()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la instrucción que borras `print(mi_lista.pop(3))` Si esta eliminando correctamente, el error viene después. Esto porque antes de eliminar tienes

> ['Pato', 'Gallina', 'Pollo', 'Lechuga', 'Pato', 'Pavo', 'Avestruz',
> 'Gato', 'Perro']

Luego de eliminar tienes

> ['Pato', 'Gallina', 'Pollo', 'Pato', 'Pavo', 'Avestruz', 'Gato',
> 'Perro']

Osea el elemento eliminado fue 'Lechuga'  que es la posicion 3 (recuerda que se enumera desde el (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...), despues de eso viene la instruccion `mi_lista.remove("Lechuga")` Pero como ya eliminaste el elemento 'Lechuga' Te muestra el error `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list` Que significa que lechuga no esta en la lista porque antes ya fue eliminado.